# How to get the Expiry field from a (Java) Date object to be send to Apple Push Notification Services?

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications

Can anyone clarify what the 4 bytes in the Expiry field of an Enhanced Notification Format (for sending to Apple Push Notification Service) mean, as in using Java to talk to APNS servers? Say, if I prepare the Date object, how do I get it into 4 bytes required to send to APNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APNS documentation states :

> **Expiry**—A fixed UNIX epoch date expressed in seconds (UTC) that
>   identifies when the notification is no longer valid and can be
>   discarded. The expiry value should be in network order (big endian).
>   If the expiry value is positive, APNs tries to deliver the
>   notification at least once. You can specify zero or a value less than
>   zero to request that APNs not store the notification at all.

If you have a Date object (lets call it `date`) that holds the date/time in which your message should expire, the 4 bytes of the expiry to send to APNS are the value of `expiry`:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance ();
cal.setTime (date);
int expiry   = cal.getTimeInMillis () / 1000L;
```

Or you can have a relative expiration interval. For example, if you want your message to expire 2 hours (7200 seconds) after being sent to the APNS server, the value of `expiry` will be :

```
int expiry = (System.currentTimeMillis () / 1000L) + 7200;
```